# What is the order of subgroup $\langle5\rangle \bigoplus\langle3\rangle$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{30} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: group-theory, direct-sum

What is the order of subgroup $\langle5\rangle \bigoplus\langle3\rangle$ of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{30} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$

I think the order will be $LCM(6,4)=12$
Because $\langle5\rangle$ has order $6$ in   $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$  and $\langle3\rangle$ has order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Comment: The reasoning given would explain why $\langle 5\oplus 3\rangle$ has order $12$; but this is a strict subgroup of the desired group.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the underlying set structure of a direct sum $G \oplus H$ is $G \times H$, so $|G \oplus H| = |G||H|$. What are the sizes of $\langle 5 \rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_{30}$ and $\langle 3 \rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_{12}$?.

Comment: Sizes are 6,4 respectively...Do you mean answer is 24?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

You're notation looks like you are making the subgroups $\langle 5 \rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_{30}$ and $\langle 3 \rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and only after that taking the sum. This gives you 24. But what you wrote is instead $\langle (5,3) \rangle \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}_{30} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. Where you put the brackets matters.

For $\langle (5,3) \rangle$, you are okay. Let's list them.

(5,3)
(10,6)
(15,9)
(20,0)
(25,3)
(0,6)
(5,9)
(10,0)
(15,3)
(20,6)
(25,9)
(0,0)